# ASP.NET Core Pages: Partials

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Is there a way to re-render a partial from a PageModel?

```
@foreach (var group in Model.Groups)
{
    <partial name="_OverviewAction" model="@group" />
}
```

The following function should replace the partial with a new one.

But this won't work because the Partial() only accepts a model from the same type as the PageModel.

```
public IActionResult OnPostDeleteGroup(string id)
{
    var group = GroupService.GetGroup(id);

    /*... some code ...*/

    return Partial("_OverviewAction", group);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean re-useable or portable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `Partial` helper method was introduced in 2.2, I believe that the intention was to allow you to pass in any model, but the actual implementation seems buggy (or to behave differently to expectations). So you can fall back on the way to call partials that works in 2.1:

```
return new PartialViewResult {
        ViewName = "_OverviewAction",
        ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<data type for the group variable goes here>(ViewData, group)
    };
```